# why the result is global name , is this caused by "this"?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
global.name ="global";

var object2 = {
    name:"My Object 2",
    doSomething:function(){
        return function(){
            return this.name;
        };
    }
};

console.log(object2.doSomething()());
```

why the result is "global", not "My Object2"?

Answer (score 3):

The function returned from the `.doSomething()` function is invoked without any context, so the value of `this` will be the global context.

Depending on what you want, you can provide a context in different ways. For example, you could have `doSomething()` always return a function that's bound to the object involved in its invocation:

```
doSomething:function(){
    return function(){
        return this.name;
    }.bind(this);
}
```

You could also explicitly provide the context when you call it:

```
console.log(object2.doSomething().call(object2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's why, right before the first call nested inside `console.log()` call, the passed argument could be thought of looking something like this

`console.log(function(){return function(){ return this.name;})`

`// Note how that the console.log method has not reached yet the (this) reference, it's still like a black box for it`

and right after the execution of the first call, it would look something like this:

`console.log(function(){ return this.name;})`

Now while executing, the `console.log()` method would resolve the `this` value and since it's executed in the global context, it would fetch the value stored in the variable `name` on the global object.

So, what counts here is where the function is called and not how or where it's defined.

**NOTE**: Your code example is not 100% correct as you defined in the first line, in implicit way, an object `global` and set a property on it named `name`  to the `"global"` value.

Answer (score -1):

`this` in that context refers to the closure that created the object - in this case it's global.

If you want it to work in its own closure, you could do something like this:

```
global.name ="global";

function MyObject(name) {
    this.name = name;
    return {
        doSomething: function(){
            return this.name;
        }
    }
}

var object2 = new MyObject("My Object 2");

console.log(object2.doSomething());
```